# New remote Branch/Head is not added after fist pushing though Android Studio

Tags: android, git, android-studio, gitlab

Recently I have migrated my Android project from Git Hub to Git Lab and Also updated the Android studio from 3.2-3.3. In the current Studio IDE, I am getting a consistent Bug while checking out and commit a new Branch.

I am using a two-layer hierarchy in the Git[Development, and Master]. Each feature is considered as a separate branch derived from Development. After feature completion and unit testing, the feature branch will merge to development with a Pull request.

For checkout a new Branch I am using the below shortcut in Android Studio.

[image]

In my previous environment[Git Hub & Old Studio], when I check out a new branch and After pushing the codebase, It will create a new Brach/Head in the remote. But now it's not happening. It's added as a new commit under the Development branch. The commit& Push done through the IDE itself.

I have checked the git status from the terminal under Studio. But it's showing the current branch as Feature. I don't know whether this is an issue in Git Lab. If anyone knows the fix, please update. I can create the remote branch terminal through command.

Comment: I don't know Gitlab or Android Studio well enough to try an answer, but I can tell you that the operation you are attempting in the screenshot is to checkout a remote branch.  Assuming you had already done this, and `development` already exists locally, you rightfully _should_ be seeing an error message.  Instead, you probably intend to just checkout `development` directly.